# Raspberry Pi HLS streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, avconv

I have a rev. B Raspberry Pi and want to stream from my Microsoft Lifecam VX-800 to a web server using HLS protocol and avconv/ffmpeg, preferably without using raspivid because it's not working (couldn't figure out why). The stream needs to be fed to jwplayer. I went through a lot of guides but none seem to be fitting my needs. Could you give me detailed instructions on how to do the live streaming or give me links to detailed tutorials that you tried and worked?

Thanks.

Comment: so you're connecting your Lifecam to your raspberry pi, and streaming that to some other server?